# Don't change vs Wouldn't change

Tags: grammar

I'm not a native speaker, and I'm having some issues with those two constructions:

> I wouldn't change X for Y.

For me, this construction gives out the idea of "not having desire of changing X for Y".

> I don't change X for Y.

This one doesn't give the idea of desire, it's just a plain statement that I won't change X for Y.

Is this correct? I'm interpreting them right? Is the second form even correct?

Comment: The first refers to a hypothetical situation in the future.  The second refers to the present, and describes a characteristic, ie one of the ways you could describe yourself.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Are both of them "correct" then? Could you please make an answer based on your comment?

Comment: I'm not sure about your context, ie what's being changed.  Can you add an example sentence to your question with real-world examples instead of X & Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but mean different things.    I think your interpretations are correct.

"I wouldn't change X for Y." refers to a hypothetical situation in the future: you could describe it as a lack of desire to change X for Y if you liked.

"I don't change X for Y." refers to the present, and describes a characteristic, ie one of the ways you could describe yourself.

They can be used interchangeably, depending on context.

For example:

"I'm thinking of taking a shortcut down Murder Alley."
"I wouldn't go down Murder Alley"

vs

"I'm thinking of taking a shortcut down Murder Alley."
"I don't go down Murder Alley"

On the face of it, both of these are simple statements of fact about person B, as described above, but the **meaning** is actually the same:  person B is giving person A some information about themselves, which is also **advice**:  they are suggesting that person A should not go down Murder Alley either.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used.  The major difference is wouldn't is past tense, and don't is present tense.  So depending on what tense you want to use depends on what word would work best.

Comment: The major difference is the mode.